# Ansible cast float to date

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and I'm wondering how can I easily cast a float to a date.

For example. I have a file and I already stat it somewhere in the early-stage of the playbook.

```
- name: Check if {{ file }} target exists
  stat: path="{{ file_location }}"
  register: file_stat
```

Later on the playbook, can I reuse the `file_stat` to get the Time of last modification of the `{{ file }}`? To be specific, I want it to be in this kind of  format: DD/MM/YY.

I did use `{{ file_stat.stat.mtime }}` but it returns me a float value like `1481440281.4`.

Is this something do-able?

Comment: You'll have to code a 5-line custom filter plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Suvorov said, you need a custom filter plugin.
You can follow this [link](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/14btv17s4n/how-to-add-custom-jinja-filters) to create the plugin.

Here is my file layout :

```
├── file_stat.yml
├── filter_plugins
│   ├── float_to_date.py
```

The content of `file_stat.yml` just as yours, and I add as `debug` task to print out the result.

```
- name: Check if {{ file }} target exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ file_location }}"
  register: file_stat
- debug:
    var: file_stat.stat.mtime | float_to_date
```

The content of `float_to_date.py`, which is the custome filter :

```
import datetime

def float_to_date(arg):
    return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(arg)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return { 'float_to_date': float_to_date }
```

Then, part of the result of this playbook :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "file_stat.stat.mtime | float_to_date": "2016-12-11 11:18:31"
}
```